# pushing data to firestore through RadDataForm

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, telerik, nativescript, dataform

I am using RadDataForm and I want to add its data to a firestore database, but it doesn't add anything. When I check firestore I find nothing.

```html
<StackLayout>
    <RadDataForm #myScrollingDataForm [source]="user" commitMode="Manual">
        <TKEntityProperty tkDataFormProperty name="firstName" index="0"></TKEntityProperty>
    </RadDataForm>
    <Button text="register" (tap)="creatUser()" horizontalAlignment="stretch"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

user.ts

```typescript
createUser(value,firstName){
    firebase.firestore().collection("user").add({name: firstName})
        .then((docRef: firestore.DocumentReference) => {
            console.log("user added, ref: " + docRef.id);
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it that you don't even see the log at all Or it just not appear in Firebase Console?

Comment: it just doesnt appear in Firebase Console....it shows "This document has no data " in Firebase Console

Comment: Are you sure you configured your app properly. What happens if you call get on collection, does it give all the records?

Comment: i managed to solve the problem thanks